System Admins Unable to View Each Other's Activities (Tasks and Events) Despite Public Read/Write Settings on Account and Contact
Hello Salesforce Stack exchange community,
I'm facing an issue regarding visibility of activities (Tasks and Events) related to Accounts and Contacts in Salesforce. Despite having the Organization Wide Defaults (OWD) set to public read/write for both Account and Contact objects, and the Activity object being controlled by the parent, our system administrators are unable to view each other's activities.
Here are the specifics of our configuration:
Organization-Wide Defaults (OWD) settings:
Account: Public Read/Write
Contact: Public Read/Write
Activity object: Controlled by parent
Despite these settings, our system admins are unable to see each other's records for tasks and events related to Accounts and Contacts. We need both system admins to have access to each other's activities.
Could someone please advise on:
Possible reasons for this issue despite the OWD settings?
Any additional settings or configurations that may be necessary to enable visibility for system admins?
Any best practices or considerations we may have missed in configuring visibility settings for activities?
Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

After investigating, I found the issue was related to Tasks and Events list view filter.By selecting "All Tasks" and "All Events" instead of "My Tasks" and "My Events" in the respective list view filter both the system admins were able to see each other's Tasks and Events.
